# how to maintain the state of the toggled div tag?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I want to hide & show the div tag when click on the  tag.
suppose i have a  tag as-

```
<div id="Change"><a href="#">More</a></div>
```

and i have another div as

```
<div id="toggle">some controls</div>
```

When i click on the `More link` then it should show my `div toggle` & should change `More to Less` & when i click on the `Less` it should `hide my div toggle` & again `text of <a> should be "More"` .
And suppose i'm having other web pages link on the same page. Then if i redirect to other page & come back to the previous page then it should maintain the previous state of the  tag as well as the div toggle.
 And if my page is contain any button which will call the server side event then after event execution it should maintain the state as same as earlier.

How to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

use cookies if you want the browser to "remember" the "toggle div" state.
use jquery and [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js) plugin to make your code easier and shorter.

here's an example of what you can do.

```
// on document ready
$(function(){

    // read the cookie and make a decision
    var toggle = $.cookie('toggle');
    if(toggle && toggle == "toggle"){
        $('div#toggle').animate({height:300},500);
        $(this).text("Less");
    }

    $('div#change>a').click(function(){
        if($(this).text() == "More"){
            //if More then toggle the toggle div.
            $('div#toggle').animate({height:300},500);
            $(this).text("Less");
            $.cookie('toggle','toggle');
        }else{
            $('div#toggle').animate({height:0},500);
            $(this).text("More");
            $.cookie('toggle',NULL);
        }
    });

})
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution with javascript, you could change the hash for the page:

```
<div id="Change"><a href="#" id="toggleButton" onclick="toggleButton();">More</a></div>

<script>
 function toggleButton() {
     if (document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerHTML === "More"){
         document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerHTML = "Less";
         window.location.hash = "Less";
     }
     else {
         document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerHTML = "More";
         window.location.hash = "More";
     }
 }
 </script>
```

This will make the page URL look like `http://mysite.com/webpage.aspx#More`

Then, when the page is loaded, you could use more javascript to look at the page hash and set the div visible/not visible as needed.

This will not work for more complex pages though.

Also, remember when using both asp.net and javascript - the asp.net server will change the ID attribute of elements with the `runat=server` attribute. This makes it difficult to use javascript with `runat=server` elements. You can solve this by giving `runat=server` elements also the `ClientIdMode="Static"` attribute.

Comment: innerText for IE and textContent for FF/Chrome would yield better results, as condition checks with innerHTML can result in unwarranted html tags being present.

Answer (score 0):

Add a css display property to the `toggle` div and use `$('.target').toggle();` on click eventhandler of div `Change`.You can also change the innerhtml of the `Change` from More to less or from less to More using `.html()`

Also to maintain the state use a hidden field.

Make sure you add ref to jquery library if you want to use `toggle`.